# ar_track_alvar fails to find IndividualMarkers with Kinect

Tags: ros, gazebo, kinect, ros-kinetic, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I cannot find a credible reason why my Kinect camera is not able to detect AR Markers, I am using [ar_track_alvar](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/ar_track_alvar?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22ar_track_alvar%22) with ROS Kinetic, Gazebo 7 and Husky robot.
To test the package I placed a single marker (size 50 cm) in front of my robot, as seen in this Figure. [image] Markers have been generated in the Gazebo simulator by running the [script](https://github.com/mikaelarguedas/gazebo_models), and later inserting them as Gazebo models (SDF files).
My launch file looks like this

```
<launch>
<arg name="marker_size" default="5" />
<arg name="max_new_marker_error" default="0.05" />
<arg name="max_track_error" default="0.2" />

<arg name="cam_image_topic" default="/camera/depth/points" /> <!-- cam_image_topic requires the type sensor_msgs/Image , put /camera/rgb/image_raw or /camera/depth/image_raw-->
<arg name="cam_info_topic" default="/camera/depth/camera_info" /> <!--/kinect_head/rgb/camera_info put /camera/rgb/camera_info-->
<arg name="output_frame" default="/base_link" /> <!-- camera_link also tried-->

<node name="ar_track_alvar" pkg="ar_track_alvar" type="individualMarkers" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <param name="marker_size"           type="double" value="$(arg marker_size)" />
    <param name="max_new_marker_error"  type="double" value="$(arg max_new_marker_error)" />
    <param name="max_track_error"       type="double" value="$(arg max_track_error)" />
    <param name="output_frame"          type="string" value="$(arg output_frame)" />

    <remap from="camera_image"  to="$(arg cam_image_topic)" />
    <remap from="camera_info"   to="$(arg cam_info_topic)" /> 
</node>

</launch>
```

Instead of depth/points and depth/camera_info, I also tried to use rgb/image_raw and rgb/camera_info in the corresponding image_topic and info_topic fields, with no results. The marker size corresponds to the exact size in the Gazebo model file, so I am supposing there is no error in there. By echoing the Kinect topics I get non empty messages, hence the plugin is working fine.
A double and visual check for this is visible in this Rviz Figure as well.

[image: Figure]

As seen both the rgb and depth camera can output the marker.

What I cannot get is the marker´s pose, and also the marker´s frame in Rviz; this simply mean that the tag is not detected at all. The /visualization_marker topic is infact empty.

[image: Here] the graph with topics is visible.

I am really stuck with it, any help would be really appreciated!

Regards,
Simone.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278307/ar_track_alvar-fails-to-find-individualmarkers-with-kinect/) by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2017-12-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-09**:
Can you please embed your images in the question instead of linking to them? This will help the question to remain self-contained should the links disappear (which happens quite often).

**Comment by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) on 2018-01-09**:
Hi jayess,
At the time I entered the question I was not able to do so, I think because I did not have enough karma. I just edited the question with Figures also.
Sorry for the previous mistake, I am newby to ROS answers.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-09**:
No worries :)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-15**:
Could you please post your solution as answer instead of as an update to your question?

**Comment by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) on 2018-02-18**:
Updated ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Solved**

It appeared that the tag could only be detected on its back side, hence I simply flipped it using SDF Gazebo code. Tag tracking was also very weak, and I often has "segmentation fault errors". I solved this by highering the tags some x-cm from the ground and highering the horizontal Kinect FOV.

Hope this might help someone in case!

---

Originally posted by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) with karma: 98 on 2018-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0